# Atmega328p resets and crashes when powering up solenoids

Tags: arduino, atmega, solenoid, flyback, solenoid-valve

I'm having problems with my PCB board based on **atmega328p** microcontroller (very similar to an Arduino standalone board).

This is my current [PCB schematics](http://www.dronyx.com/board-ok.png) and [Eagle board](http://www.skeetty.com/board.png).

**SCHEMATICS UPDATED!**

[image]

I use connectors on *VSX, VDX, MOT1A, MOT2A, MOT2A, MOT2B* to switch ON and OFF solenoid valves (the valves are rated as 12VDC, 2A at max).

The board works randomly fine only for few seconds or minutes until the micontroller crashes or resets and I think this happens due to solenoids noise.

The main power is 12VDC, 35A (used for the valves and the relay) and then I use a 5VDC voltage regulator to power on the atmega328p.

As you can see, I already added flyback diodes across each mosfet, but may be this is not enough to prevent solenoid noise. I also twisted each couple of wires (maximum wire length is 90 cm) which connect the valves pins to VSX, VDX, MOT1A, MOT2A, MOT2A, MOT2B connectors and I added an additional diode in parallel on each valve pins.

How can I solve the problem?
I was thinking to add **100nF ceramic caps** between **VCC and GND** and **AREF and GND** and **AVCC and GND** as close as possible to the microcontroller pads and another **100nF cap** in parallel on each valve pins.
Do you think it can be enough to solve the problem?

Unfortunately, I think I can't separate the solenoid power source from the atmega328p power source since they are currently sharing the same GROUND.

What can I do to solve the problem by continuing using the same PCB board?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the relay at the extreme right of the PCB is supposed to do, but if one pair of screw terminals is a mains input and the other pair is a relay-switched output it's not wired correctly. It will just short out the mains: [Illustration](http://i.imgur.com/7rcRku1.png). There is also a second issue with that relay; the clearance between the relay coil and the common terminal of the switch is unnecessarily small. If the relay is used to switch the mains, this could be dangerous.

Comment: Thank you, jms for your support. The relay has no function on this board and I'm not using it. It is not even mounted on this layout. Its task was to short the two terminals to act like a switch, but I'm not using it.

Answer (score 2):

Cut that trace running up from pin 22 and jumper it directly back to the middle pin on the 7805 with a fly wire.

Add a 10uF X7R or X5R cap directly between pin 7 and 8.

Make the layout better next time or use a 4-layer board.

Comment: So, should I cut the GND traces (pins 22 and 8) from the atmega and directly connect them to the 7805 central pin (GND)?

Comment: Yes, jumper from pin 8 directly back to GND on the 7805

Comment: Can you explain me the purpose of this operation, please? The middle pin of 7805 isn't the same GND for the entire circuit? I wanna improve my electornics knowledge, so I would like to know what happens if I do this. Thank you!

Comment: Current from the MOSFETs is flowing through the micro GND trace. The cut and jumper avoids the ground bouncing around. This may not be enough but it may help. Next step is to add series gate resistors of a few hundred ohms.

Comment: Thank you! I already have the series gate resistors of 220R between the atmega output and the MOSFEST gate. Are they not correct?

Comment: @MarcusBarnet The resistors you have added are *parallel* resistors, being between the gate and the drain. Don't get me wrong, they are a great addition (they ensure that the MOSFETs stay off when the AVR resets), but they won't help against voltage spikes caused by excessively fast switching. Their current values (220 ohms) are way too low trough, normally you want those parallel resistors to have a value of a few thousand ohms (e.g. 10 k), especially if you add the gate *series* resistors mentioned (series as in between the IO pins and the gates).

Comment: I don't see them on the schematic...except Q1

Comment: Sorry guys, I did a mistake and I uploaded an old schematics. I edited my first topic and replaced it with the REAL schematics. As you can see, I'm using 220R series resistors. Do you think they are OK?

Comment: Yes, looks okay. You could even go higher but it's probably not necessary.

Comment: I added a 1000uF main capacitor filter across +12v and gnd con the main connector. I also added a 100uF between pin 7 and pin 8. There was already a 100uF cap between aref and gnd but it was not close to the atmega so I added another cap directly on aref and gnd pads. It is OK or I have to remove the old cap? I've cut the pin 22 trace and I connected it directly to the 7805 gnd. Is there anything else I can do to improve the board?

Comment: A ceramic cap is requested - 100uF sounds a bit high to be a ceramic, though not impossible. These details do matter. An electrolytic cap will not work as well on that position because of inductance and ESR.

Comment: I did a typo in my previous topic, I used 100nF ceramic capacitors. Unfortunately, the board worked fine for few hours and then it started to fail again! :( Now, everytime I power it up, the atmega crashes after few seconds. I can't understand why so small solenoids give me so many problems. Is there still anything I can do to solve the situation? Or I have to give up? :(

Comment: Do I have to limit the maximum current for the solenoid?
It says that it requires a maximum current of 1.9A, but i'm not limiting the current in any way. Or the solenoid will only ask for 1.9A in any case?

Can the solenoid drain over current (more than 2A) and get burned? May be the problem is that I need to limit the current!

What do you think about this?

Answer (score 0):

It is very unlikely that something will help to fix this board layout. This PCB design has a very poor ground, so somewhere the ground bounces, and a glitch kills the processor. Why so many folks here are not using ground pour? Then the ground return path for relays must be separated from the ground for low-power control electronics. It should be designed in first. Then, a main capacitor is missing, on input 12V jack, which is the main power rail for all relays.

Comment: Hello Ali, thank you for your answer. This is my first time in PCB designing and so I did several errors. Is there any way to solve my problem? For example, where can I place the main capacitor? Across +12v and ground?

Comment: 100nF As main capacitor should be enough?

Comment: No. I would put a 100uF or 2,200uF or something. Maybe you will  be able to drop thick blue wires to beef up the ground return from power electronics.

Comment: And why do you have heat sinks on FETs? The transitors should be operating in ON of OFF mode, and dissipate almost nothing.

Comment: And I miss the 35A parameter. Clearly the traces (as drawn) can't support this kind of current. You can try to put a quarter of pound of solder on top to beef them up as well.

Comment: I'm not using the heat sinks on the FETs, I just added them to the board design in Eagle, but I'm not using them for real. Do you think I will have to add also bypass capacitors on VCC and GND close to the microcontroller?

Comment: I'm just using a 12V, 35A battery, but I really don't need all that ampere since they will fry the board for sure. The maximum current needed by the board is 2A for each valve.

Comment: A 100nF bypass at microcontroller is a must. 2A times 10 valves is still a lot

Comment: Do you think the D1 diode on the +12V input is correct? Or I have to remove it? It is a 1N4004 diode which can only draw 1A. The cap PC1 is 100uF, should I replace it with the 2200uF?

Comment: The cap PC1 only works for 5V digital rail, 100uF is definitely ok. The diode is ok, it provides at least some de-coupling from main power rail. Without extra big capacitor at 12V power jack the inductance of supply wires will cause drops to the rail on every valve switch.

Comment: Thank you, so I need to add a big cap between +12V and GND before the diode and PC1 if I well understood.

Comment: Ali, the schematics added to my first message was not the updated one. I edited my first topic to add the real schematics.

Comment: Do I have to limit the maximum current for the solenoid? It says that it requires a maximum current of 1.9A, but i'm not limiting the current in any way. Can the solenoid drain over current (more than 2A) and get burned? May be the problem is that I need to limit the current! What do you think about this?

Comment: Solenoid coils should be driven to solenoid manufacturer's specifications. If it is 12V, then it should be 12V regardless of current taken. Otherwise they might not operate to their mechanical specifications.

Comment: The problem is that the manufacturer says that the solenoid is 12VDC, 3.7 ohm and 1.9A. The measured current between the mosfet and the solenoid is 2.9A which is quite higher than expected.  May be this is the problem which makes the board to block.

Comment: If I use a voltmeter in series between the mosfet and the solenoid to measure the current and I power on the board.. than the board works perfectly!! I'd I remove the voltmeter, than the board don't work again. This is very strange!! Why it works correctly only if the voltmeter is connected to the circuit?

Comment: Is your DMM an auto-ranging DMM?

Comment: Or DMM leads work as inductance, which slows di/dt and causes less switching spikes and ground bounce